# Ajax save canvas image is corrupted (decoding incorrectly?)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to take a canvas data and save it as a png file. I am using the following ajax code and keep getting a saved image but the image is corrupted. Perhaps I have the wrong $_REQUEST attribute?

Any help is appreciated.

```
  var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
  var imageURL;
  $.ajax({
            url: "saveimage.php",
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'data_url': dataURL },
            complete: function(xhr, textStatus) {
            // Request complete.
            },
            // Request was successful.
            success: function(response, textStatus, xhr) {
                console.log('Response: ', response);
                // Conversion successful.
                if (response.status_code === 200) {
                    imageURL = response.data.image_url;
                    // Paste the PNG image url into the input field.
                    document.querySelector('img').src = imageURL;
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Some error occured.
                console.log('Error: ', errorThrown);
            }
        });
}

<?php
file_put_contents('images/'. rand().'.png', base64_decode($_REQUEST['data_url']));
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

So as it turns out, the way to do this was to explode the data apart because the datatoURL actually contains more info than we need for the image. This code worked for me and hopefully it can help someone else too:

```
<?php
$data = $_REQUEST['data_url'];
list($t, $data) = explode(';', $data);
list(, $data)      = explode(',', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);
$filename='images/'. rand().'.png';
file_put_contents($filename, $data);
$response = array("image_url"=>$filename,"status_code"=>200);
echo json_encode($response);
?>
```